# Opening 'New' Document?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have some code implemented in my myDocument.m file that simply attempts to load the last used document upon launch. However, upon launching from a fresh install, (or running after **deleting** the last used file) a 'new' document window does not appear. Does anyone know what to add to my code to do this? Here it is:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    NSURL *lastURL=[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:lastURL display:YES error:nil];
    if (lastURL!=nil)
    {
     [docController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:lastURL display:YES error:nil];    
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    NSArray* urls = [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] recentDocumentURLs];
    if ([urls count] > 0){
        NSURL *lastURL= [urls objectAtIndex: 0];

        if ([[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:lastURL display:YES error:nil]){
                   return NO;
             }      

    }

    return YES;
}
```

EDIT

I changed it and tried it out it should work now.

Comment: @Justin - it works in the sense that it opens the last used document, but when I clear the list and open the app, I want a new document to appear

Comment: I got it, just tried it out. An exception was being thrown before but I fixed it.

Comment: There’s no need to check if `lastURL` is `nil` since arrays cannot contain `nil`. Also, you should check the return value of `-openDocumentWith…` and return `NO` if it is different from `nil`.

Comment: @Bavarious: Its not working for me, I'm also getting an error in the log (not related, since I commented it out):
'2011-02-08 18:45:10.434 myApp[35178:a0f] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'

Comment: @Justin: thanks I want to see if it works :/ I'm getting the error I posted above in the log now (it might have been showing up for a while? I haven't seen it before though)

Comment: Did you try the latest version with the if ([urls count] > 0) ?

Comment: Yeah I'm still getting that error in the log, and it's not working. However, I think this will work. I just need to figure out the other problem (posted below). Thanks for your help!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940916/nscf-array-out-of-bounds

Comment: Yeah I just double checked that it works. I would go to Run - > Stop On Objective-C Exceptions to track it down.

Comment: @Zakman411 Be sure to fix Justin’s code and check the return value of `-openDocumentWith…`. If it returns `nil`, it means the last document couldn’t be opened, hence your method should return `YES`. Currently Justin’s code returns `NO` if the last document couldn’t be opened.

Answer (score 0):

What is `docController`, and why are you sending `-openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:` twice? Note that that method returns a document, not a URL, so using the return value as a URL wouldn’t work anyway.

The following is a cleaner, equivalent code:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    id lastDoc = [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController]
        openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:lastURL
        display:YES error:NULL];
    return (lastDoc == nil);
}
```

However, it still doesn’t explain why you don’t get an untitled document. What happens if you comment out `-applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:` so that the application follows standard Cocoa behaviour? It could be the case that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: This actually throws an error because lastURL isn't declared. Should I just add that in?

Comment: @Zakman411 Use `-recentDocumentURLs` as explained in Justin’s updated answer.