# NSCF Array Out of Bounds?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I have a fairly simple application using Core Data, and a couple Array Controllers (in IB, no code files for them, other than the xcdatamodel file). When I run my application, I get the following error in the log (the app still runs, but no window appears until I go to File > New Document):

`2011-02-08 18:45:10.434 MyApp[35178:a0f] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0`)

I have no references in my myDocument.h or .m files to an array. The error is not critical (the app still runs), but it disables some of my code to load the last used document or (if that doesn't exist) load a fresh document. The app simply loads up with no visible windows. I would **greatly** appreciate some help on this and will award the answer quickly :)

**EDIT: Here is the applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile code:**

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    NSArray* urls = [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] recentDocumentURLs];
    if ([urls count] > 0){
        NSURL *lastURL= [urls objectAtIndex: 0];

        [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:lastURL display:YES error:nil];    
        return NO;

    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Post the code you’re using in `-applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:`.

Comment: On the Xcode menu press Run -> Stop On Objective C Exceptions to track down where it happens.

Comment: @Bavarious: I edited the post to include it. However, the error occurs even when I comment that section out..

Comment: Please try out Justin's suggestion.  There's nothing wrong with the code you have posted and as the error still happens when you comment it out, clearly the error is not where you think it is.

Comment: @Justin: I don't see that option? Is it Debug w/ Breakpoints on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to post here, I don't have the right to comment everywhere for the moment.

@Zakman411: Justin is saying you should enable the "Stop on Objective-C Exceptions" item in the Run menu, then launch the debugger. gdb should show you where the exception is thrown exactly.